# Sandbox Debug Logs not showing?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, debugging

I have an issue where the debug logs are not consistently being written in our Sandbox environment.  For the past 45 minutes cs4 has not written a debug log successfully, and we have tested this from multiple browsers.  Trying to get to the bottom of our error, but it is making it tough when we don't see anything.

Is there anything known with Sandboxes not always debugging correctly?  We are using Public Sites and setting the debug to the Site.com Guest User.  It has previously worked, but then we are hitting a issue and the debug log isn't being written?  Is there any documentation on how/when debug logs are written I can reference?

Comment: You've definitely set the Log Type and the correct Start/End date?

Comment: Open a case with support if this is an option.

Comment: Will do.  Curious if anyone has had similar situation.  Yes, the Log Type is setup correctly.

Comment: Is this something that is happening only in the sandbox and not in production? are the logs related to code in a managed package?

Comment: makes SFDC debugging similar to the problem faced by the European Space Agency when the Philae lander stopped transmitting on comet 67P/Churyumov